# Get postal code with autocomplete service

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to show postal code with address. I get address here but i can't find postal code to create custom auto address drop down.

```
var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
var searchStr = '';
$("#search").keyup(function() {
    var searchStr = $("#search").val();

    service.getPlacePredictions({ input: searchStr, types: ['geocode'],
                        componentRestrictions:{ country: 'us' } },
    function (predictions, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            var results = document.getElementById('results');
            jQuery("#results").empty();
            for (var i = 0, prediction; prediction = predictions[i]; i++) {
                jQuery("#results").append('<li>' + prediction.terms[0].value +','+ prediction.terms[1].value + '</li>');

                    console.log(prediction);

            }
        }
    });

});
```

I can't get postal code from those code.

Comment: You are using getPlacePredictions() method, which is only going to return predictions of places. What you want to do is use a method like getPlace(), that will return Place Details.

Answer (score 3):

The `getPlacePredictions` method returns an array of prediction objects each of which expose a `placeId`. From Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service):

> To retrieve information about the place, pass this identifier in the
>   placeId field of a [Place Details request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details).

You can then get the `postal_code` from the `address_components` array returned in the results of the Places Details call.

Hope this helps!